# App Engine Deploy Error 500

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a problem and i don't know what should I do.
so, I've created a little web application using Java(JSP-Servlet) & App Engine API
It is working in locale, but when I deployed it, it gives me that error:

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.
```

and, in the logs of the administration pages

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: persiste/EmployeServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-50f1863c6e652dbb(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

---

when i changed java ( from java 7 to  java 6 ) and execute the application, i get this errors:

7 août 2012 13:02:52 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
ATTENTION: failed Testv2: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: test/Testv2Servlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

7 août 2012 13:02:52 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
ATTENTION: failed com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@1522de2{/,D:\Etudes\Stage Dirham Express\workspace\testv2\war}: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: test/Testv2Servlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

7 août 2012 13:02:52 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
ATTENTION: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@15f4a7f: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: test/Testv2Servlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

7 août 2012 13:02:52 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
ATTENTION: EXCEPTION 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: test/Testv2Servlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)

at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)

at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:190)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)

at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)


at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)

at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)

at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)

at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)

at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)

at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)

at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)

at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)

at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)

at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)

at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)

at
```

com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.reloadWebApp(JettyContainerService.java:315)

```
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ScannerListener.fileChanged(JettyContainerService.java:259)

at org.mortbay.util.Scanner.reportChange(Scanner.java:464)

at org.mortbay.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:330)

at org.mortbay.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:280)

at org.mortbay.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:232)

at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)

at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

7 août 2012 13:02:52 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
ATTENTION: com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ScannerListener@113e9fd failed on 'D:\Etudes\Stage Dirham Express\workspace\testv2\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you compile your jars under one version of the Java SDK and try and run them on a different version. The App Engine production environment supports Java 6 (aka v1.6), so you should also use Java 6 on your local machine when compiling code.

If you have multiple versions of Java installed on your computer, make sure you're using the correct one when you compile your code.

If you're using Eclipse, make sure it's also configured to use Java 6. After changing versions, you should also 'clean' your project to remove outdated classes.

Answer (score 0):

Version number is 51.0. App engine does not support dots.