# Google App Engine java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/ritesh/RiteshServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Hi i installed java 6 and using eclipse Juno on ubuntu.i installed google app engine plugins(1.7.0 sdk) .i created a web project Ritesh when i deploy it on google it gives me 500 internal server error Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 in google app engine .i go through some queries but unable to solved out.i am new to ubuntu.can any one please help how to solve this error.please help me. here is error logs related to exception

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/ritesh/HelloWorld2Servlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-6c4455b8f6b9bd6b(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614604/app-engine-deploy-error-500

Answer (score 1):

Bytecode major version 51 means it was compiled under JDK7. GAE supports JDK6. You should check config in your IDE.